# GRUB2 wont start after installing Ubuntu on separate harddisk

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

This isn't the first time I've installed ubuntu. The first time I had ubuntu and w7 booting from the same drive (worked fine using conventional tricks). This time I am booting from a separate hard drive (not so good this time).

Now. I have w7 installed first on my main ssd.
Then had ubuntu installed on a separate hard drive.
After installing ubuntu 10.10, grub2 didn't show, so I went ahead did the conventional methods of recovering grub, as listed on this website: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD

I tried both method 1 and method 2.
No errors on both. I get something along the lines of "Installation complete. No Errors."
Then I reboot.
Loads straight to Windows, no grub menu

//My linux drive is sda5//My W7 is on sdb//

-I tried shift on bios, no good.

The only method that worked was using Super Grub2. I dont like the idea of putting in a cd to start linux every time.

My question is, are the conventional methods the wrong way to go, because ubuntu is installed on a separate hard drive? Also, note there are no errors when I do method 1 and method 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got in trouble by using these instructions:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover

First of all, you must start your system from a live cd. Then

"**METHOD 3 - CHROOT**

This method of installation uses the chroot command to gain access to the broken system's files. Once the chroot command is issued, the LiveCD treats the broken system's / as its own. Commands run in a chroot environment will affect the broken systems filesystems and not those of the LiveCD.

**1)** Boot to the LiveCD Desktop (Ubuntu 9.10 or later). Please note that the Live CD must be the same as the system you are fixing - either 32-bit or 64-bit (if not then the chroot will fail).

**2)** Open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal).

**3)** Determine your normal system partition - (the switch is a lowercase "L")

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you aren't sure, run

```
df -Th
```

Look for the correct disk size and ext3 or ext4 format.

**4)** Mount your normal system partition:

Substitute the correct partition: sda1, sdb5, etc.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

*Example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt*

**5)** Only if you have a separate boot partition:
sdYY is the /boot partition designation (for example sdb3)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot
```

**6)**
Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

**7)**
Chroot into your normal system device:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**8)** If there is no /boot/grub/grub.cfg or it's not correct, create one using

```
update-grub
```

**9)**
Reinstall GRUB 2:

Substitute the correct device - sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number.

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

**10)** Verify the install (use the correct device, for example sda. Do not specify a partition):

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

**11)**
Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard

**12)**
Unmount virtual filesystems:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
```

**13)**
If you mounted a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/boot
```

**14)**
Unmount the LiveCD's /usr directory:

```
sudo umount /mnt/usr
```

**15)**
Unmount last device:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

**16)**
Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

"

Comment: Thanks method 3 did solve the problem of getting grub2 to show. I also discovered that fdisk -l was incorrectly stating my harddrives. fdisk stated that my W7 drive was /dev/SDB, but when I checked grub.cfg, it was actually /dev/SDD.

Comment: I'm glad it work. I've never seen it fails ;-)

Comment: Just a note, when executing step 10:
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdc Received mssg:
"sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Sector 33 is already in use by FlexNet; avoiding it. This software may cause boot or other problems in future. Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track." Anyway it finishes with the usual:
installation finished. No error reported. So I will try your solution till the end and get back with the final result.

Comment: Nop :( didnt work for me. Is there an "update-grub" missing?

Comment: No it is not missing. I think it would be the FlexNet problem.

Answer (score 0):

On which drives did you install grub? Try to install grub to `/dev/sda` and **also** to `/dev/sdb` (and whatever drives you also have).
May it be possible that you installed it to `/dev/sda5` or something like this? Or you installed it to `/dev/sda` and the bios boot-order prefers `/dev/sdb` with existing win-loader?

Comment: I have only tried sda5 because that is the Linux drive. My sda drive was partitioned so it can be used on windows as well. And as for you second question. I do believe that sdb is the preferred boot-order. I suppose it would make sense to try it in sdb. Should I be trying sdb(the entire disk) or sdbX the partition of windows. There is also the 100meg recovery partition under sdb.

Comment: I tried both my partitioned linux drive, sda/sda5 and my w7 boot drive sdb/sdb2, no good. Goes straight to W7 at start up. So far the only method that seems to work is Super Grub2, which is annoying.